# NG-Grid Filter not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a really basic grid using Angular.js and NG-GRID with the showFilter: set to true.
However if I search for the value in the  Marketing Start Date Column, 200101011.  It doesn't show.  Actually as soon as I start typing a 2 in the filter text it should find all four records, but only 2 show up....
Here's the Plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/D3nFkQ
Thank you.

Comment: plunker no longer working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be the null values in your table. The search does not seem to go past a cell containing null. Hence the strange filtering behaviour. If you replace the nulls with empty strings or other values the search works perfectly.
There is an issue logged on ng-grid on GitHub - [filter search box returns prematurely when cell contains an object](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/603). Since null is an object the solution suggested may work for you.